# form variables not passing

Tags: php, variables, post, null

It seems my code is correct, however the posted variables in the form do not echo in the update user settings page in the form. I have echoed the posted ids from the input in the database but I cannot get the variables to show. I have done this in Codeigniter fine but am trying to do it in pure php with my own framework.

```
$users = new Users($db);
```

comes from my init.php file that is called at the beginning of the file below.

when I do

```
<?php var_dump($user['first_name'])?>
```

I get Null

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name']) )
{echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));} else { echo
$user['first_name']; }?>">
```

Comment: The form will update any text put in the fields when viewed. However, it will not show the latest posted input from user so the user knows what to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try $_REQUEST['first_name'] first before submitting it to array.

```
<?=$_REQUEST['first_name']?> 

<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name']) )
{echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name']));} else { echo
$user['first_name']; }?>">
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

Is your form using get or post method? If it is using get method $_POST will be null. If you use $_REQUEST, it will show the result regardless of the http method used.

Comment: <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<?php
$first_name =  $_POST['first_name'];
?>
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php if (isset($first_name)){ echo htmlentities(strip_tags($first_name));} else { echo $users['first_name']; } ?> ">
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already have: $first_name  = htmlentities(trim($_POST['first_name']));

Comment: u are using $user i thing change it with $users

Comment: will u tell me form submit on same page or other page

Comment: form submits on the same page.

Comment: If I use $users instead of $user it makes everything disappear.

Answer (score 0):

try it  i think its work fine  and solve your problam

```
<?php
     if(isset('name of submit button ')) // example $_POST['submit'];
        {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php  echo htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['first_name'])) ?> " >
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $user['first_name']; ?> " >
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```